# MSSQL Full backup execution time

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue where a full backup on a MSSQL server randomly takes ~2.5 the time to complete. Is there any option in SQL Management Studio or Stored Procedure that would tell me what cause this giant slowdown.

I have many MSSQL server running and that particular one is internal only and backup happen at 5am in the morning while there is no one in the office until 7:30-8:00. Backup is typically taking a steady 14 minutes 20 seconds (plus or less 10 seconds) but once or twice per week it suddenly takes upward of 45 minutes.

The backup size is growing but it's really minor like 40-50 mb per day while the backup size is sitting currently at around 21 gb. All daily transaction are stable in size too. When i have a slow backup the transaction of the previous day is not any different is size than the day before neither the other "normal" days.

The only logs i see simply give me start time and end time of the maintenance plan which is useless as it's the total runtime.

Comment: Size of your database? Are you using compression in your backups? What is the script or tool you're using to schedule backups? What kind of disk is behind the server? Are other applications or processes outside of your SQL Server instance also running on this server (e.g. antivirus)?

Comment: Is there a possibility that on the days you have 14 minutes and 20 seconds backups, instead of full backups you're having differential or transactional backup, and on the day, it takes 45 minutes you're having a full backup?

Comment: @J.D. Size of database is roughly 19 gb, there are no compression and i am using the standard maintenance plan. What kind of disk that i cannot get this information. All i know is i have 3 virtual drives that are alone on their own controller. This server have only 1 other application and it's disaster recovery image done on sundays at lunch time

Comment: @Ineffable21 No, there is only 3 maintenance plan on this server. 1 running to clear logs each Sunday night, second is transaction backup every 15 min all days and last is Full backup at 5am each day. 3 simple things. All database are in full recovery mode as well.

Comment: @Franck check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/292440/db-backups-taking-too-long.html

Comment: A 19 GB database taking 14 minutes to backup sounds a little unusually slow in itself. I'd find out what disks are behind your server, and where the backup is being saved to. Is the backup stored on a network location or local to the SQL Server? It's probably something unexpectedly running either in SQL Server or outside the instance but on the server itself, consuming resources. Disk issues either physically or virtually (I've seen VMWare / Veeam bug out badly) are possible, though I'd say much less likely. Regardless, you should enable compression in your backups which may speed them up too.